# Shouldn't this question be closed as Off Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

While browsing today, I noticed the question
[What influence did H.P. Lovecraft have on science fiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268/can-howard-phillips-lovecraft-be-considered-a-sci-fi-author)

I realize it's as old as the hills, effectively, but I distinctly remembered seeing in [the FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq) that "Genre classification: Is X Science Fiction?" questions are on the Off Topic list. Shouldn't this question already be closed, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason it's still open (or was, as I just closed it) was its age.  It likely predated the determination that those types of questions are not a good fit for this site.  Then once that decision was made, it was missed in the cleanup.

Comment: I edited and reopened, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the question is from the very early days of the site and fell through the cracks when we cleaned up questions that did not comply with the guidelines in the FAQ.

However, I think the question is fundamentally a reasonable one, with reasonable answers. So I edited it to make it ostensibly not about defining the genre, but about Lovecraft's influence, which is what the answers mostly dwelt about anyway. I reopened the question since I believe it to now be firmly on-topic.